# How can I be sure PayPal transaction is done completely in PHP?

Tags: php, paypal

I have 3 files (simple script) to make a payment with PayPal (v1 API) :

1: index.htm (start payment):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Replace "test" with your own sandbox Business account app client ID -->
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&disable-funding=credit,card"></script>
    <!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
    <script>
      paypal.Buttons({
        // Sets up the transaction when a payment button is clicked
        
        style: {
          shape: 'rect',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'horizontal',
          label: 'paypal',
          
        },
        
        createOrder: (data, actions) => {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
              amount: {
                currency_code :'USD',
                value: '77.44' // Can also reference a variable or function
              }
            }]
          });
        },
        // Finalize the transaction after payer approval
        onApprove: (data, actions) => {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
          
            // Successful capture! 
            window.location = "paypal-verify.php?id="+data.orderID;
           
          });
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

2: paypal-client.php (connect to api):

```
<?php
    
    use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\PayPalHttpClient;
    //use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\SandboxEnvironment;
    use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\ProductionEnvironment;

    
    class PayPalClient {
        
        Public static function client()
        {
            return new PayPalHttpClient(self::environment());
        }
        
        public static function environment()
        {
            $clientId = getenv("CLIENT_ID") ? : "XXXX";
            $clientSecret = getenv("CLIENT_SECRET") ? : "YYYY";
            
            //return new SandboxEnvironment($clientId,$clientSecret);
            return new ProductionEnvironment($clientId,$clientSecret);
        }
        
    }
```

3: paypal-verify.php (to verify payment):

```
<?php 

    require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
    require __DIR__.'/paypal-client.php';
    
    use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersGetRequest;
        
    class GetOrder
    {
        
        public function verify($orderId)
        {
            
            $reply = new stdClass();
            $reply->verify = false;
        
            try
            {
                
                $client = PayPalClient::client();
                $response = $client -> execute (new OrdersGetRequest($orderId));
                
                $statusCode = $response-> statusCode;
                $transactionId = $response->result->purchase_units[0]->payments->captures[0]-> id;
                //$email     = $response->result-> payer->email_address;
                //$name      = $response->result-> purchase_units[0]->shipping->name->full_name;
                //$amount  = $response->result-> purchase_units[0]->amount->value;
                
                if ($statusCode == 200 || $statusCode == 201) {
                
                    $reply->verify = true;
                    $reply->ref= $transactionId;
                    
                } else {
                    
                    $reply->ref= "error:" .$statusCode;
                    
                }
                
            }
            
            catch (\PayPalHttp\HttpException $e) 
            {
                     
                //echo $e->getMessage();
                $reply->ref = "error in verifying transaction!";
                    
            } 
            catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $e) 
            {
                    
                //echo $e->getMessage();
                $reply->ref = "Error in verifying transaction!";
                    
            }
            catch (\PayPalHttp\IOException $e) 
            {
                    
                //echo $e->getMessage();
                $reply->ref = "Error in connecting paypal server!";
                    
            }           
            
            return $reply;
        }

    }
    
    
    $id = empty($_GET['id']) ? "" : $_GET['id'];
    if (!count(debug_backtrace())) 
    {
        $order = new GetOrder();
        $reply = $order->verify($id);
        
        var_dump($reply);
    }
```

Apparently the code is working but the question :

**My method to check that payment settled or not (by comparing statusCode with 200 or 201) is enough and standard?**

Any other suggestion about whole code would be appreciated.
With the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be sure, don't use the actions.order.create / .capture client-side functions. These are for simpler use cases. Any number of problems could prevent your system from recording a transaction after the fact.

Instead, use the v2/checkout/orders API and make two routes (url paths) on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order'. You can use the (recently deprecated) Checkout-PHP-SDK for the routes' API calls to PayPal, which I see in your question -- or your own HTTPS implementation of first getting an access token and then doing the call. Both of these routes should return/output **only** JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should verify the amount was correct and store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as reserving product or sending an email) immediately *before* forwarding return JSON to the frontend caller. In the event of an error forward the JSON details of it as well, since the frontend must handle such cases.

Pair those 2 routes with this frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server .  (If you need to send any additional data from the client to the server, such as an items array or selected options, add a `body` parameter to the fetch with a value that is a JSON string or object)

Comment: Ok. I removed index.htm part and now making payment request on server side based on REST API (http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/) but my question still exists : How can I be sure that payment completed? Checking the [total amount] and approved [state] is enough?

Comment: PayPal-PHP-SDK uses the v1/payments API and is very old and completely unmaintained at this point. Even the newer v2/checkout/orders Checkout-PHP-SDK was deprecated recently, but you certainly shouldn't be using the older one for anything

Comment: I changed my codes to cURL in PHP. Although user will be redirected to PayPal site but I can change style of button and get rid of popup window.

Comment: Why redirect payers away from your site? That is an old flow. Much better to keep your site loaded in the background for an in-context payment experience.

Comment: You are right but PayPal doesn't allow to change style of button completely when I'm using JS . Also some users don't like popup :/

Comment: The popup has higher conversion; more people are confused by the redirect or don't proceed with it than dislike the popup.